# Is it possible to link the axes of two surface plots for 3d-rotation?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, axes

Say I have two 2-dimensional matrices of equal size and create a surface plot for each of them.
Is there a way to link the axes of both plots, so that one can 3D-rotate both of them simultaneously in the same direction?

Comment: `surf(A); hold on; surf(B);`? This will add both plots to the same coordinate frame though. You want to have 2 frames?

Comment: Yes, two frames would be better..

Comment: There is a one-liner that simplifies @umlum 's callback solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Playing with `ActionPostCallback` and `ActionPreCallback` is certainly a solution, but probably not the most efficient one. One may use `linkprop` function to synchronize the camera position property.

```
linkprop([h(1) h(2)], 'CameraPosition'); %h is the axes handle
```

`linkprop` can synchronize any of graphical properties of two or more `axes` (2D or 3D). It can be seen as an extension of the `linkaxes` function that works for 2D plots and synchronizes the `axes` limits only. Here, we can use `linkprop` to synchronize the camera position property, `CameraPosition`, the one that is modify when one rotate an `axes`.

Here is some code

```
% DATA
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z1 = sin(R)./R;
Z2 = sin(R);

% FIGURE
figure;
hax(1) = subplot(1,2,1);    %give the first axes a handle
surf(Z1);
hax(2) = subplot(1,2,2);    %give the second axes a handle
surf(Z2)


% synchronize the camera position
linkprop(hax, 'CameraPosition');
```

You can have a list of the graphical properties with

```
graph_props = fieldnames(get(gca));
```

Comment: Oh linkprop() is nice indeed. This solution also gives continous updates while my answer only synchronizes once the user lifts the mouse button.

Comment: This worked! but I find that `linkprop([h(1) h(2)], 'View');` works even better than `'CameraPosition'`.

Comment: @ESala, thanks for the tip; however, how is `View` better than `CameraPosition`? Is `CameraPosition` not as robust?

Comment: I found that `View` feels more consistent. With `CameraPosition` there is some kind of snapping going on when you're at a small angle to one of the coordinate axes.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to register a callback on rotation events and synchronize the new state across both axes.

```
function syncPlots(A, B)
% A and B are two matrices that will be passed to surf()

s1 = subplot(1, 2, 1);
surf(A); 
r1 = rotate3d;

s2 = subplot(1, 2, 2); 
surf(B);
r2 = rotate3d;

function sync_callback(~, evd)
    % Get view property of the plot that changed
    newView = get(evd.Axes,'View'); 

    % Synchronize View property of both plots    
    set(s1, 'View', newView);
    set(s2, 'View', newView);
end

% Register Callbacks
set(r1,'ActionPostCallback',@sync_callback);
set(r1,'ActionPreCallback',@sync_callback);
set(r2,'ActionPostCallback',@sync_callback);
set(r2,'ActionPreCallback',@sync_callback);

end
```